# Removing specific words from text file

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, textfiles

I have a text file tat contains `email:name | address = date time`
I want remove everything that comes after name from each line and leave me just `email:name` is there a way to do that?

Comment: Could you give some example lines and expected result.

Comment: What characters can be present in `name`? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](https://superuser.com/help) and how to [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired parts in a fictitious sample text (as a test case only for your needs )

```
email:info@volkswagen.de | address = 2007-12-24T18:21:00Z
email:info@toyota.de | address = 2007-12-24T18:21:00Z
email:info@hyundai.de | address = 2007-12-24T18:21:00Z
```

can be replaced with Notepad++ by following steps

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\ \|.+)`
- Replace with: `nothing`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

resulting in

[image]

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work

Comment: @Amin - please see my edit **CHECK** *Regular expression*.

Comment: Thanks finally worked